Glare node outputs black square
I've rendered an animation to an EXR image sequence and am now compositing it.
The glare node outputs a black square where the Nishta sky texture sun is.
This does not happen when having the composite directly in the render.
So I beleive I have done something wrong with the exporting options in the output or the glare node is f*ckd in 4.1, 4.0 and 3.6.
I have not tested other versions.


The artifact in blender 3.6:

Rendering output. To be clear this the output for the 3d render itself and not the composite:

Even when the mix has been turn all the way to -1.0 it is still outputting a black square so it isn't an issue with glare it self:

Heres two frames showing how the black square changes from frame to frame depending on location:
First frame:

Second frame:

The few frames after this remained as is shown in the second image until it disapered when the sun was out of frame.
Here is how it behaves with other glare types
and the full node setup. I have tried turning off the nodes before the glare:


It feels more like a faulty EXR than something else. Maybe share your blend file with packed texture with https://blend-exchange.com/.

Here's the blend file with a frame connected.
(https://blend-exchange.com/b/Koz240pK/)

I figured it out. The DWAA (lossy) compression caused it.
Changing the compression from DWAA (lossy) to zip (lossless) fixed the problem.
Either lossy compression gets weird at higher float values or DWAA is a bad compression choice for higher values.
